# How to solve TypeError error in Jupyter Notebok

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I'm trying to run the `model.py` code in this [Github](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car) repository.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook. I've cloned this repository and have started the jupyter notebook from this directory (where the repo is cloned) so that no error occurs in importing modules.

When I run this part of the code of `model.py`file:

```
def main():
    """
    Load train/validation data set and train the model
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Behavioral Cloning Training Program')
    parser.add_argument('-d', help='data directory',        dest='data_dir',          type=str,   default='data')
    parser.add_argument('-t', help='test size fraction',    dest='test_size',         type=float, default=0.2)
    parser.add_argument('-k', help='drop out probability',  dest='keep_prob',         type=float, default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('-n', help='number of epochs',      dest='nb_epoch',          type=int,   default=10)
    parser.add_argument('-s', help='samples per epoch',     dest='samples_per_epoch', type=int,   default=20000)
    parser.add_argument('-b', help='batch size',            dest='batch_size',        type=int,   default=40)
    parser.add_argument('-o', help='save best models only', dest='save_best_only',    type=s2b,   default='true')
    parser.add_argument('-l', help='learning rate',         dest='learning_rate',     type=float, default=1.0e-4)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #print parameters
    print('-' * 30)
    print('Parameters')
    print('-' * 30)
    for key, value in vars(args).items():
        print('{:<20} := {}'.format(key, value))
    print('-' * 30)

    #load data
    data = load_data(args)
    #build model
    model = build_model(args)
    #train model on data, it saves as model.h5 
    train_model(model, args, *data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it gives the following error:

```
<ipython-input-16-6e1430362122> in <module>
     32 
     33 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 34     main()

<ipython-input-16-6e1430362122> in main()
     26     data = load_data(args)
     27     #build model
---> 28     model = build_model(args)
     29     #train model on data, it saves as model.h5
     30     train_model(model, args, *data)

<ipython-input-6-b4a45377398f> in build_model(args)
     21     model = Sequential()
     22     model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
---> 23     model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
     24     model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
     25     model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py in __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, groups, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
    651                bias_constraint=None,
    652                **kwargs):
--> 653     super(Conv2D, self).__init__(
    654         rank=2,
    655         filters=filters,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py in __init__(self, rank, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, groups, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, trainable, name, conv_op, **kwargs)
    132                conv_op=None,
    133                **kwargs):
--> 134     super(Conv, self).__init__(
    135         trainable=trainable,
    136         name=name,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    516     try:
--> 517       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    518     finally:
    519       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __init__(self, trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    338     }
    339     # Validate optional keyword arguments.
--> 340     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
    341 
    342     # Mutable properties

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
    806   for kwarg in kwargs:
    807     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 808       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
    809 
    810 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
```

I have no idea what does this mean.

P.S: I replaced `args = parser.parse_args()` with `args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()`(just telling incase this is the cause of error)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the linked GitHub repository was written for Keras version 1.2.0 and TensorFlow version 1.1.0 (see [the conda environment spec](https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_simulate_a_self_driving_car/blob/master/environments.yml)). Keras 1.2.0 [was released in December, 2016](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/1.2.0), and the package has changed significantly since then. The `subsample` argument in `keras.layers.Conv2D`, for example, was present in Keras 1.2.0 but has since been removed.

To use the linked GitHub repository, I would create a new conda environment using the `environment.yml` file included.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

See [the conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) for more information.

Comment: I actually installed `keras`, `tensorfow` and `moviepy` separately, so the latest version of these are installed. For e.g, keras version is 2.4.3. Considering that, what changes do I have to make in the code?

Comment: Keras has changed over the years, and arguments that were valid years ago might no longer work. This seems to be the case here. You should install Keras 1.2.0 and TensorFlow 1.1.0. If you are familiar with conda, you should create a conda env like I demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the main() function in model.py?
If you want to execute the model.py file with parameters from the Jupyter Notebook the simplest way is:

```
import model as mdl

class Args:
  data_dir = ...
  test_size = ...
  ...

args = Args()
mdl.main(args)
```

Comment: You mean to say that I
 should remove the main function? And what values shall i set for these params?

Comment: This answer does not get at the underlying issue, which is that the code was written for an older version of keras

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell exactly what was happening, but the `main()` function is defined to process the arguments of a terminal run such as `> python model.py --args`, not on an interactive session like when you're on Jupyter.

If you plan to use it on  Jupyter Notebooks it would be easier to just get rid of `main()` and pass the arguments for `load_data()`, `build_model()` and `train_model()` directly as user defined variables.

For example, rewriting the `load_data()` function would look something like this:

```
def load_data(data_dir, test_size):
    """
    Load training data and split it into training and validation set
    """
    #reads CSV file into a single dataframe variable
    data_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), data_dir, 'driving_log.csv'), names=['center', 'left', 'right', 'steering', 'throttle', 'reverse', 'speed'])

    #yay dataframes, we can select rows and columns by their names
    #we'll store the camera images as our input data
    X = data_df[['center', 'left', 'right']].values
    #and our steering commands as our output data
    y = data_df['steering'].values

    #now we can split the data into a training (80), testing(20), and validation set
    #thanks scikit learn
    X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=0)
    return X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how exactly to do that? Shall i remove the passed arguments?

Comment: I just edited the answer to give you an example.

Comment: This answer does not get at the underlying issue, which is that the code was written for an older version of keras.

Comment: Thank you @jakub for pointing this out. In any case, if @ssmalik is running this interactively on a Jupyter notebook it makes little sense to keep running this with `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: Yes I agree. You do offer very helpful advice. I just wanted to note that this will not solve the problem.